# Customize default django password validators message

Tags: python, django, validation

I am using default password validators from Django

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 6,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to translate the text return by the `function get_help_text()` for each validator without creating new validators.

Comment: I dont think so. You can override the method, but will still you need to inherit the class then.

Comment: So you think I should create my own  or override the method in my case?